# How to identify points of change in a curve?

Tags: math, calculus

I'm working with some datasets that have a repeated pattern like shown below, often with dozens or hundreds of these peaks. My aim is to identify the average point across all of the peaks where the curve has quickly dropped off and begun to level out (the top arrow). I also want to find the average point where the curve begins to flatten out (the bottom arrow). I'm hoping to use python to identify these points.

[image: image of curve]

Comment: This is not a python question, but a math question. You're basically asking for places where the function's derivative suddenly goes from being relatively large (steep function) to being fairly small.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html to start with.